# Automatically connect to network drives after connecting to VPN

Tags: powershell, vpn, openvpn, network-drive

I have several mapped network drives that I can only access when on my company's LAN or when connected to the VPN using OpenVPN.

When I connect to the network in our office, the drives automatically connect. However, when I connect via the VPN, only two of the drives automatically connect (I tried `net use /persistent:yes` but that didn't seem to make a difference, so maybe I'm not understanding that command).

What's odd to me is that the rest of my drives say "unavailable" as the status when I type `net use`. If I click on the drive in Windows Explorer, the drive status is then blank. Those drives do not display when I use `get-PSDrive`. Not sure if that's related to the autoconnect or not.

Any ideas for what I can do to automatically connect to my other drives?

[image]

Comment: The best I have come up with is a script to reconnect drive mappings to run after a VPN connection is made.

Comment: The drives are not mapping because you do not have the credentials to access the remote machines.  Are the machines in the same domain?  I would contact your network admin for answer.  I think something is wrong with the Group Policy or a domain issue.  When you logon with the VPN you should have the same domain access as when you locally login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the solution that ended up working for me:

I used Task Scheduler to create a task that automatically runs when I access OpenVPN. The tasks launches a .cmd file with the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted" >> "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
PowerShell -File "C:\Scripts\MapDrives.ps1"
```

This calls the following PowerShell script.

```
$start = Get-Date
$endTime = $start.AddMinutes(3)  # Set end time 3 minutes from start

$MappedDrives = Get-SmbMapping | Where-Object { $_.Status -ne "Ok" } | Select-Object LocalPath, RemotePath, Status

# Function to log messages to a file
function LogMessage {
    param(
        [string]$Message,
        [string]$Color,
        [switch]$Display=$False
    )

    $logFilePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "mappinglog.txt"
    Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $Message
    if( $Display ) {
        Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor $Color
    }
}

# Create or append to the log file
$scriptDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$logFilePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "mappinglog.txt"
if (Test-Path $logFilePath) {
    Remove-Item -Path $logFilePath 
}

New-Item -Path $logFilePath -ItemType File | Out-Null

Write-Host "Reconnecting drives...." -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "Press the CTRL+C hot key combination to cancel." -ForegroundColor Cyan

while ($MappedDrives -and (Get-Date) -lt $endTime) {
    $error.clear()
    foreach ($MappedDrive in $MappedDrives) {
        if ($MappedDrive.Status -eq "Disconnected") {
            if (Test-Path $MappedDrive.LocalPath) {
                LogMessage "Success: $($MappedDrive.LocalPath)\ reconnected to $($MappedDrive.RemotePath)" -Color Green -Display $True
            } else {
                LogMessage "Failed: Unable to reconnect $($MappedDrive.LocalPath)\ to $($MappedDrive.RemotePath)" -Color Red
            }
        } elseif ($MappedDrive.Status -eq "Unavailable") {
            if (Test-Path $MappedDrive.RemotePath) {
                New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $MappedDrive.LocalPath -RemotePath $MappedDrive.RemotePath -Persistent $true
            }

            if (Test-Path $MappedDrive.LocalPath) {
                LogMessage "Success: $($MappedDrive.LocalPath)\ connected to $($MappedDrive.RemotePath)" -Color Green -Display $True
            } else {
                LogMessage "Failed: Unable to connect $($MappedDrive.LocalPath)\ to $($MappedDrive.RemotePath)" -Color Red
            }
        } elseif ($MappedDrive.Status -eq "Reconnecting") {
            LogMessage "Pending: $($MappedDrive.LocalPath)\ is automatically reconnecting to $($MappedDrive.RemotePath)" -Color White -Display $True
        }
    }
    $MappedDrives = Get-SmbMapping | Where-Object { $_.Status -ne "Ok" } | Select-Object LocalPath, RemotePath, Status
}
```

Comment: Nice, though note that you can consolidate your `powershell` calls to a single one: `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Scripts\MapDrives.ps1"`. Unless you're still running PS v2, you can replace `$scriptDirectory` with `$PSScriptRoot`. Adding `-Force` to `New-Item -Path $logFilePath -ItemType File` will automatically replace any existing file.